# Is it possible for a Command Button to show another Command button in Access?

Tags: vba, button, ms-access-2007

Access novice here. I've been using it for about a week now, and can do most things with enough googling and trial and error.
One question though, I have a form that Im using to add participants into the database. At present, i have 2 buttons, one that opens the MALE add user form, and then another button which opens the FEMALE add user form.

What i was wondering is, is it possible to create a main button (called "ADD USER" for example), that when pressed, shows the two other MALE and FEMALE buttons for the user to choose from?

Sorry if that makes no sense. Basically, can I make a button that when pressed, makes two more buttons visible?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are way to do this:

you could create those m/f-buttons and make a function which toggles visibility of your buttons on execution of addUser-button.

you could make an additional dialog, which is called by addUser-button

but my suggestion would be - use radio-buttons for male/female and their setup to execute addUser correctly ;) mainly, because I find this more intuitive and efficient.

[image]

like this, now you can access those to know which one is selected, or you can use a global variable or a property to be setup by those radio-buttons and then accessed by other objects, like an addUser-Button.

Hope this was clear enough - just try and look into those suggestions to find your way ;)